# Error When using re-base with react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created an application that gets all the data for various tables from static objects stored in their own files. I want to take these and move them onto Firebase so I can save my various data states. I'm really struggling to find a way to connect re-base and firebase together after multiple installs.

I get the error: TypeError: _base__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.base is undefined when I load my Loads module.

Here is my code for one of my components, note that LOADS is not my app component, could this be causing issues?

```
import {base} from '../../base';
class Loads extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tableData: null,
        status: null
    }
}
    componentWillMount(){
    this.loadDataRef = base.syncState('loadData', {
        context: this,
        state: 'loadData'
    })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    base.removeBinding(this.loadDataRef);
}
```

Here is the code in base.js where I've imported firebase and rebase:

```
import Rebase from 're-base'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
  apiKey: "this is a secret ;)",
  authDomain: "yes",
  databaseURL: "yes",
  projectId: "yes",
  storageBucket: "not sure",
  messagingSenderId: "21",
  appId: "yessir",
  measurementId: "alright"
 }

 const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
 const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database());

 export { base }
```

I've already done npm install --save re-base firebase, although I do get the following warnings:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for firebase@7.14.3: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 ||   >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: firebase@7.14.3
 npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @firebase/firestore@1.14.3: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @firebase/firestore@1.14.3
 npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @grpc/grpc-js@0.8.1: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @grpc/grpc-js@0.8.1
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck here for a a day now looking at various ways of doing it but I can't seem to figure anything out.